# Programmatically check Java 7(jre7) or higher version is installed on my system

Tags: c#

i want to check whether Java 7 or higher version of java is installed on my machine or not. i am using below code to find this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the file path of the installed java run time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>full path of java run time.</returns>
    private static string GetJavaPath()
    {
        RegistryKey javaRuntime = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment");
        string currentVerion = javaRuntime.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
        string javaSubVersion = (javaRuntime.OpenSubKey(currentVerion)).GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();
        string filePath = Path.Combine(javaSubVersion, @"bin\javaw.exe");
        return filePath;
    }
```

I need all the javaw.exe (java version) on my system.
Please look into this.

Comment: The higher version is precisely jre1.8 aka jre8

Comment: @C.Champagne - sorry for confusion. i need all the java version installed on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` will give you the current version but the other jre versions can also be retrieved with under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`.

Note that it might be worth also looking for JDKs (since they embed a JRE and are no necessarily referenced under the keys here above). You can find them at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit`.